# How to use xgboost.train()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, xgboost, valueerror

I am new to XGBoost and I want to use the train() function but when I try to I get the following error

```
146 else:
147     try:
148         main()
149     except KeyboardInterrupt:
150         print("KeyboardInterrupt, exiting")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xgboost/core.py in __init__(self, params, cache, model_file)
938         for d in cache:
939             if not isinstance(d, DMatrix):
940                 raise TypeError('invalid cache item: {}'.format(type(d).__name__))
941             self._validate_features(d)
942 

TypeError: invalid cache item: DataFrame
```

my code is

```
    import xgboost as xgb
    xgb_params = {
        "objective": "multi:softmax",
        "eta": 0.3,
        "num_class": 62,
        "max_depth": 10,
        "nthread": 4,
        "eval_metric": "merror",
        "print.every.n": 1
        #"silent": 1
    }
    clf = xgb.train(params=xgb_params, dtrain=df, num_boost_round=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

XGB requires you to turn your dataframe into a DMatrix for it to process

```
        d_train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
        d_test = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)
```